# How do I selectSingleNode in xml with vbscript and classic asp?

Tags: xml, vbscript, asp-classic

From [here](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/xmldom/quickref/node_selectsinglenode.html):
xml:

```
<Vocabulary> 
   <Word type="noun" level="1"> 
      <English>cat</English> 
      <Spanish>gato</Spanish> 
   </Word> 
   <Word type="verb" level="1"> 
      <English>speak</English> 
      <Spanish>hablar</Spanish> 
   </Word> 
   <Word type="adj" level="1"> 
      <English>big</English> 
      <Spanish>grande</Spanish> 
   </Word> 
</Vocabulary>
```

I created the xml file put it in the same directory as the classic asp file:

```
    <%

    Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 
    objXMLDoc.async = False 
    objXMLDoc.load("vocabulary.xml") 

    Set Node = objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("Word/Spanish")
    document.write(Node.text)

%>
```

But I get this:

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: 'objXMLDoc.documentElement'

/so-rms/reports/xmltest.asp, line 7

What am I doing wrong?  They get the element.  I get the error.  Thanks.

Edit:  I put this in:

```
If objXMLDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
    response.write objXMLDoc.parseError.errorCode & "ERROR CODE </br>"
    response.write  objXMLDoc.parseError.reason & "REASON CODE </br>"
    response.write  objXMLDoc.parseError.line & "LINE CODE </br>"
End If
```

and got:

-2146697210ERROR CODE

System error: -2146697210. REASON CODE

0LINE CODE 
tried from below:

```
dim path: path = Server.MapPath("vocabulary.xml")
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if not fso.FileExists(path) then
    Response.Write "path '" & path & "' not found"
end if
Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0") 
objXMLDoc.async = False 

if not objXMLDoc.load("vocabulary.xml") then
    ' report loading error
     response.write "error"
end if
'objXMLDoc.load("vocabulary.xml") 
If objXMLDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
    response.write objXMLDoc.parseError.errorCode & "ERROR CODE </br>"
    response.write  objXMLDoc.parseError.reason & "REASON CODE </br>"
    response.write  objXMLDoc.parseError.line & "LINE CODE </br>"
End If
Set Node = objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("Word/Spanish")
document.write(Node.text)
```

EDIT:

I also changed the xml file to a URL of a working XML return (bing maps) and it worked.  So I guess it's the file.  Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `objXMLDoc.load(path)`, where `path` is the result from the call to `MapPath()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your xml document is not loading. The `load()` method returns a `bool` to indicate whether the file has loaded correctly, so you can check

```
if not objXMLDoc.load("vocabulary.xml") then
    ' report loading error
end if
```

The `parseError` also property has a `srcText` property which you can use to determine where a parse issue has occurred in the file.

It's also a good idea to check that the file exists on the path you're using. Use `Server.MapPath()` and a `Scripting.FileSystemObject` to do this:

```
dim path: path = Server.MapPath("vocabulary.xml")
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if not fso.FileExists(path) then
    Response.Write "path '" & path & "' not found"
end if
```

Additionally, I recommend using a later version of the XML library, `MSXML2.DomDocument`

Comment: not sure then. I've tried this: `xmldoc.loadXML("<Vocabulary><Word type=""noun"" level=""1""><English>cat</English><Spanish>gato</Spanish></Word><Word type=""verb"" level=""1""><English>speak</English><Spanish>hablar</Spanish></Word><Word type=""adj"" level=""1""><English>big</English><Spanish>grande</Spanish></Word></Vocabulary>")` and the XML loads correctly, so the XML itself is ok